# Disconnect user when hit bandwidth

Tags: freeradius

I configure the FreeRadius server on Centos 6.x and authentication work fine on mysql database.
But I can't use the sqlcounter to check the preiodicaly sum bandwith are use my users from the mysql database.

I make a sqlcount like this:

```
sqlcounter  wifi_Limit{
count-attribute = Acct-Input-Octets
counter-name = Mikrotik-Total-Limit
check-name = Mikrotik-Total-Limit
reply-name = Session-Timeout
sqlmod-inst = sql
key = User-Name
reset = never
query = "SELECT ((SUM(AcctInputOctets)+SUM(AcctOutputOctets))) FROM radacct WHERE UserName='%{%k}'"
```

}

and also insert the wifi_limite in the "site-available default" authorize{} like this:

```
poyrazwifi_Limit{
    reject = 1
}
if(reject){
    reject
}
```

and I insert the "Mikrotik-Total-Limit" attribute in the radcheck like this:

```
insert into radcheck(username,attribute,op,value) values('test','Mikrotik-Total-Limit',':=','999999')
```

Now this configuration is work fine when user after used the total bandwith "999999" disconnect pppoe connection manoaly after that this user can't login again.

But I like to disconnect user automatically when the use total bandwidth "999999".

Please advise me to fix this problem.
Thank You

Answer (score 4):

First, You have defined

> poyrazwifi_Limit

In authorize section, which differs from sqlcounter name you have configured :-

> sqlcounter wifi_Limit{

Second, You have configured sqlcounter and given

> reply-name = Session-Timeout

You don't need this, rather this is a wrong configuration. This will send whatever bytes of data is left for the user to browse as Session-Timeout.

For example you have configured "Mikrotik-Total-Limit" as 999999 for a user, and if user has browsed 999990 bytes out of it.

So if the user authenticates a reply attribute of Session-Timeout=9 will be replied. So after 9 seconds user will be de-authenticated regardless whether user has browsed remaining 9 bytes or not, which I don't think is what you want.

So you can simply configure the counter as :-

```
sqlcounter  wifi_Limit{
count-attribute = Acct-Input-Octets
counter-name = Mikrotik-Total-Limit
check-name = Mikrotik-Total-Limit
sqlmod-inst = sql
key = User-Name
reset = never
query = "SELECT ((SUM(AcctInputOctets)+SUM(AcctOutputOctets))) FROM radacct WHERE UserName='%{%k}'"
```

and authorize section as :-

```
authorize {
......
wifi_Limit
......
}
```

Third, Now on how to disconnect user automatically when it reaches the data limit set. You can use unlang to achieve that, So you have to check each accounting packet and use the following piece of code to disconnect user :-

```
accounting {
......
if ( "%{sql: SELECT ((SUM(AcctInputOctets)+SUM(AcctOutputOctets))) FROM radacct WHERE UserName='%{User-Name}'}" > "%{sql: SELECT value from radcheck where username='%{User-Name}' and attribute='Mikrotik-Total-Limit'}" ) {
     update disconnect {
            User-Name = "%{User-Name}"
            Calling-Station-Id = "%{Calling-Station-Id}"
     }
}
......
}
```

NOTE: For this your NAS should listen to your Radius's COA or POD requests, And NAS should be configured as COA server in FreeRadius clients.conf file